# Influential linux settings on socket behaviour and performance

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, throughput

I'am looking forward to improve my application speed/throughput, sending packets from a UDP socket in C.

I want to tune the performance of my system in order get some extra Mb/s.

I have already looked into :

> /proc/sys/net/core

> /proc/sys/net/ipv4

> /proc/sys/net/ipv6

From those, I know that `wmem_max` helps me increase the write size of my socket buffer. I'am wondering what else I can change, keeping in mind that my goal is to increase the performance of sending packets:

`ls /proc/sys/net/core/`

```
busy_poll                     fb_tunnels_only_for_init_net  netdev_budget                 rmem_default                  wmem_default
busy_read                     flow_limit_cpu_bitmap         netdev_budget_usecs           rmem_max                      wmem_max
default_qdisc                 flow_limit_table_len          netdev_max_backlog            rps_sock_flow_entries         xfrm_acq_expires
dev_weight                    max_skb_frags                 netdev_rss_key                somaxconn                     xfrm_aevent_etime
dev_weight_rx_bias            message_burst                 netdev_tstamp_prequeue        tstamp_allow_data             xfrm_aevent_rseqth
dev_weight_tx_bias            message_cost                  optmem_max                    warnings                      xfrm_larval_drop
```

Comment: You can increase the size of the _kernel_ socket buffers: `int c_sndbuf_sz = 100 * 4096; setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &c_sndbuf_sz, sizeof(c_sndbuf_sz));
` Likewise for the receive buffer size.